# Checking probabilities and random numbers (NetLogo)

Tags: random, probability, netlogo

I'm writing to have an explanation about checking probabilities in a model built by NetLogo.
I have a circumstance that can happen with a probability, for example, of 60%...
Thus I generate a number with

```
let trial random 100
```

So, it's not clear to me if I have to verifiy that trial is greater than 60 or lower equal than 60, so that the probability is satisfied.

Which is the correct way?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the result is **less than** the probability (not less than or equal). For example:

```
if random 100 < 60 [
  do-something
]
```

Using `random 100` will give you a number between 0 and 99 (inclusive). In the example, numbers 0 to 59 will meet the condition, i.e., 60 numbers out of the 100 possible numbers: a 60% probability.

Comment: @NicolasPayette please, is this answer above the only way how to include the probability of some event happening into NetLogo model?

Comment: @maycca, it is the most common way of handling probabilities but there are other possibilities too. It depends on what you want to do...